# How to alter routes defined in route_callbacks?

Tags: routes, 9, event-subscribers

Usually I alter static routes in routes subscriber:

```
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $route = $collection->get('gutenberg.media.load_media');
    if ($route) {
      $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\gutenberg_adv\Controller\MediaController::loadMedia');
    }
  }
```

However I this does not work for routes defined in routes_callback, so this does not work for search route for example:

```
$route = $collection->get('search.view_node_search');
if ($route) {
  $route->setDefault('_controller',
      '\Drupal\wi_misc\Controller\SearchController::view');
}
```

So how to alter search route controller?

Comment: Did you set the `search` module as a dependency of your own module ?

Comment: A full example of overriding the SearchController can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522792/6046296

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the weight of the execution of the `alterRoutes` function.
You can override the `getSubscribedEvents` function:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        RoutingEvents::ALTER => [
            'onAlterRoutes', 1
        ],
    ];
}
```

Notice that i call `onAlterRoutes` instead of `alterRoutes`. This is because in the parent class this is a wrapper for the called function:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[RoutingEvents::ALTER] = 'onAlterRoutes';
    return $events;
}
```

The higher your number (= weight) is, the earlier it gets executed (or the other way around).
I would try with some high and some low numbers and check the result.

I have never tried it with this specific eventbut i used this method to solve other problems with events in some `RouteSubscriber`.

If you use drush to clear your cache (which you should after changing code in a `RouteSubscriber`) then you can also use `var_dump($route);` to ensure your route does exist and is loaded correctly. The dump will get displayed in the cmd.

Comment: unfortunately this does not affect at all
the route definitely exists, I checked it
but Drupal still uses default controller